# Adding Contact Page to Flask Admin

Tags: python, flask, flask-admin

I have a Flask-Admin project I am working on and am looking to add a contact us page. I am following the example on https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/intro-to-flask-adding-a-contact-page--net-28982

This issue is that it is designed for Flask but all my templates are based on the Flask-Admin template.

```
@app.route('/contact', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def contact():
  form = ContactForm()

  if request.method == 'POST':
    if form.validate() == False:
      flash('All fields are required.')
      return render_template('contact.html', form=form)
    else:
      msg = Message(form.subject.data, sender='contact@example.com',     
          recipients=['email@email.com'])
      msg.body = """
      From: %s <%s>
      %s
      """ % (form.name.data, form.email.data, form.message.data)
      mail.send(msg)

      return render_template('contact.html', success=True)

  elif request.method == 'GET':
    return render_template('contact.html', form=form, admin=admin)
```

The contact.html  extends two admin templates

```
{% import 'admin/layout.html' as layout with context -%}
{% extends 'admin/base.html' %}
```

as a result there is an error message thrown.

> jinja2.exceptions.UndefinedError: 'admin_view' is undefined

I know I can amend the template to remove the extending the admin templates however the navigation for the whole site is done by

```
{{ layout.menu() }}
{{ layout.menu_links() }}
```

so ideally I would like to get the contact us page working with the admin template. I'm sure not sure how to pass the whole admin context across.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use `flask_admin.base.BaseView.render` method to process your templates with flask-admin context. It may look like this:

```
from flask_admin import BaseView, expose

class ContactsView(BaseView):
    @expose('/')
    def index(self):
        # Here are the contents of your "contact" route function
        return self.render('contact.html', form=form, admin=admin)
```

You can activate this view the same way as `ModelView` instances:

```
admin.add_view(ContactsView('Contacts', url='/contacts'))
```

Comment: This is failing to start the application with "RuntimeError: Working outside of application context."

Comment: allright, that's because i exposed __init__ instead of index sorry